# Torch code producing CUDA Runtime Error

Tags: runtime, pytorch

a friend of mine implemented a sparse version of torch.bmm that actually works, but when I try a test, I have a runtime error (that has nothing to do with this implementation), that I don't understand. I have seen a few topics about if but couldn't find a solution. Here is the code, and the error:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     tmp = torch.zeros(1).cuda()
     batch_csr = BatchCSR()
     sparse_bmm = SparseBMM()

     i=torch.LongTensor([[0,5,8], [1,5,8], [2,5,8]])
     v=torch.FloatTensor([4,3,8])
     s=torch.Size([3,500,500])

     indices, values, size = i,v,s

     a_ = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(indices, values, size).cuda().transpose(2, 1)
     batch_size, num_nodes, num_faces = a_.size()

     a = a_.to_dense()

     for _ in range(10):
        b = torch.randn(batch_size, num_faces, 16).cuda()
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        time1 = time.time()
        result = torch.bmm(a, b)
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        time2 = time.time()
        print("{} CuBlas dense bmm".format(time2 - time1))

        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        time1 = time.time()
        col_ind, col_ptr = batch_csr(a_.indices(), a_.size())
        my_result = sparse_bmm(a_.values(), col_ind, col_ptr, a_.size(), b)
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        time2 = time.time()
        print("{} My sparse bmm".format(time2 - time1))

        print("{} Diff".format((result-my_result).abs().max()))
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sparse_bmm.py", line 72, in <module>
    b = torch.randn(3, 500, 16).cuda()
  File "/home/bizeul/virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 65, in _cuda
    return new_type(self.size()).copy_(self, async)
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered at /b/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCTensorCopy.c:18
```

When running with the command CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1, I get the error :

```
/b/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:121: void indexAddSmallIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 1, SrcDim = 1, IdxDim = -2]: block: [0,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `dstIndex < dstAddDimSize` failed.
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/b/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THCS/generic/THCSTensorMath.cu line=292 error=59 : device-side assert triggered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sparse_bmm.py", line 69, in <module>
    a = a_.to_dense()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered at /b/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THCS/generic/THCSTensorMath.cu:292
```

Comment: ok, so cuda is technically asynchronous in nature, so that triggered assert error does not come with a stack trace.

Try running your script like this in your terminal: 

`CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 python your_script.py` 

and update your question

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post

Comment: So what is your question *exactly*?

Comment: How to make the code works, I don't understand the error, I'm a mathematician, I don't know so much about coding

Answer (score 1):

The indices that you are passing to create the sparse tensor are incorrect.

here is how it should be:

`i = torch.LongTensor([[0, 1, 2], [5, 5, 5], [8, 8, 8]])`

**How to create a sparse tensor:**

Lets take a simpler example. Lets say we want the following tensor:

```
  0   0   0   2   0
  0   0   0   0   0
  0   0   0   0  20
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 3x5 (GPU 0)]
```

As you can see, the number (2) needs to be in the (0, 3) location of the sparse tensor. And the number (20) needs to be in the (2, 4) location.

In order to create this, our index tensor should look like this

```
[[0 , 2],
 [3 , 4]]
```

And, now for the code to create the above sparse tensor:

```
i=torch.LongTensor([[0, 2], [3, 4]])
v=torch.FloatTensor([2, 20])
s=torch.Size([3, 5])
a_ = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(indices, values, size).cuda()
```

**More comments regarding the assert error by cuda:**

`Assertion 'dstIndex < dstAddDimSize' failed.` tells us that, its highly likely, you've got an index out of bounds. So whenever you notice that, look for places where you might have supplied the wrong indices to any of the tensors.

Comment: EDIT : My bad, I got it !